# How to update a column which is not in NEW / OLD sets with a trigger?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table x with, say, three columns: a, b, mult. I insert values like this:

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b) VALUES (3, 5)
```

I want AFTER INSERT trigger to update column mult like this: mult = a * b. 
The problem is that mult is not in NEW / OLD set of columns and I can't make a simple assignment:

```
NEW.mult = NEW.a * NEW.b
```

Is it possible to make a trigger with desired behavior?
P.S. This is a simplified example, the real case involves importing data from .csv with fixed set of columns. Thanks!

Comment: Show your trigger attempt. If it's a `FOR EACH ROW` (`INSERT`) trigger all columns should be there in the `new` pseudo record.

Comment: @stickybit, you are right, thank you! I rewrote my trigger function like this: 
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mult () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
 NEW.mult = NEW.a * NEW.b;
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql` 
and trigger itself like:
`CREATE TRIGGER test
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON x FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mult();`
and everything worked out well